# What does "having budgets" in this context mean?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

> To overcome this problem, I believe primary education should teach
>   children about the importance of **being within \ having** budget(s).

A native English speaker suggests to write "having budgets" instead of "being within budget".

Why "being within" is wrong and "having budgets" is correct, and please explain what "having budgets" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Having budget" - When there is still money left in the pot

"Having budget" - Setting out your spending limits in advance to ensure you don't run out of money in the period

"Being within budget" - Finishing the period of time without exceeding the budget

[Google Defs.](https://www.google.com/search?q=budget+definition&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB848GB848&oq=budget+de&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.4287j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

In the statement above:

> To overcome this problem, I believe primary education should teach children about the importance of being within budget.

...teach children about the importance of not exceeding their set expenditure for a set period of time.

> To overcome this problem, I believe primary education should teach children about the importance of having budgets.

...teach children about the importance of setting an expenditure for a set period of time.